# dependency injection vs partial application in Scala

Tags: scala, oop, functional-programming

Is there any benefit to using partially applied functions vs injecting dependencies into a class? Both approaches as I understand them shown here:

```
class DB(conn: String) {
  def get(sql: String): List[Any] = _
}

object DB {
  def get(conn: String) (sql: String): List[Any] = _
}

object MyApp {
  val conn = "jdbc:..."
  val sql = "select * from employees"
  
  val db1 = new DB(conn)
  db1.get(sql)
  
  val db2 = DB.get(conn) _
  db2(sql)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class is usually used when the dependency is longer-lived or used by multiple functions. Partial application is more common when the dependency is shorter-lived, like during a single loop or callback. For example:

```scala
list.map(f(context))

def f(context: Context)(element: Int): Result = ???
```

It wouldn't really make sense to create a class just to hold `f`. On the other hand, if you have 5 functions that all take `context`, you should probably just put those into a class. In your example, `get` is unlikely to be the only thing that requires the `conn`, so a class makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks Karl! In Scala that function still has to live within an object anyway, so it seems like that's as much work as making a class. I guess one benefit is that for a short-term dependency, it's just more consistent to have both inputs be defined in the same place (function signature) rather than broken out into a constructor...especially if there are even more than 2 parameter lists.

Answer (score 2):

Using partially-applied functions is somewhat simpler, but the `conn` is passed to the function each time, and could have a different `conn` each time it is called. The advantage of using a class is that it can perform one-off operations when it is created, such as validation or caching, and retain the results in the class for re-use.

For example the `conn` in this code is a `String` but this is presumably used to connect to a database of some sort. With the partially-applied function it must make this connection each time. With a class the connection can be made when the class is created and just re-used for each query. The class version can also prevent the class being created unless the `conn` is valid.

Comment: Thanks Tim! That's a good point about the class having sort of multiple points in time at which you can execute something...during instantiation and during the method call. Maybe a more modular approach would have been to pass a re-usable already established connection or pool rather than a string. That said, are there advantages to the partially-applied function approach? It seems to be advocated in functional-programming things I've read.